# Providing read only access to users from another group to a folder belonging to the home directory of a user from different group

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, group, chown

So I have got two groups `fruits` and `vegetables`. `mango` is a user belonging to `fruits` group. There's a folder named `insecticide` in the home directory of `mango`. I want to provide read-only access to the group `vegetables` to  the `insecticide` folder.

Logged in as the user `mango`, I tried running command

```
$ chown mango.vegetable insecticide
chown: changing ownership of 'insecticide': Operation not permitted
```

**EDIT:**
      ls -l outputs:

```
mango@node1:~$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 mango fruit 4096 May 31 13:48 pests
-rw-r--r-- 1 mango fruit    0 May 31 13:47 xyz.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 mango fruit 4096 May 31 16:00 insecticide
```

Comment: `sudo chown mango:vegetable insecticide`?

Comment: Add output of `ls -l insecticide` to your question.

Comment: sudo chown mango:vegetable insecticide gives the following error "mango is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

Comment: ask your admin for help

Answer (score 1):

Mango as an ordinary user can't set the group on a object he owns to a group he is not a member of.

So he either needs to be added to group vegetable or needs root to do the ownership change.